# How do I use .index to search for an item's position in list within a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm currently creating a program that requires me to format call functions back to classes. The one issue I'm running into is I cannot return an item's position in a list of multiple lists. I'll give you an example:

```
class Global():
    str_input = ""
    str_input_prv_word = ""
    str_input_nxt_word = ""

    prv_word = ""
    cur_word = ""
    nxt_word = ""

class Dog():
    wolf = [['fat', 'small'],[1, 3]]

input = "That's a small wolf"

def lis_str():
    ##### SPLIT INPUT STRING INTO DUPLICATE LISTS #####
    Global.str_input = input.split()
    Global.str_input_prv_word = input.split()
    Global.str_input_nxt_word = input.split()
lis_str()

def ya_done():
    ##### WHY CAN'T I FIND THE POSITION? :( #####
    print(Global.prv_word)
    print(Global.cur_word)
    print(Global.nxt_word)
    ##### PRINT POSITION OF ADJECTIVE DESCRIBING DOG IN DOG LIST #####
    exec(f"""if Global.prv_word in Dog.{Global.cur_word}:
    print(Dog.{Global.cur_word}.index('{Global.prv_word}'))""")


def create_words():
    ##### CREATE NEXT WORD FOR GLOBAL CLASS #####
    if len(Global.str_input_nxt_word) != 0:
        if len(Global.nxt_word) == 0:
            Global.nxt_word = Global.str_input_nxt_word.pop(1)
        if len(Global.nxt_word) != 0:
            Global.nxt_word = Global.str_input_nxt_word.pop(0)
    if len(Global.str_input_nxt_word) == 0:
        None
    ##### CREATE CURRENT WORD AND PREVIOUS WORD FOR GLOBAL CLASS #####
    if len(Global.str_input) != 0:
        if len(Global.cur_word) != 0:
            Global.prv_word = Global.str_input_prv_word.pop(0)
        Global.cur_word = Global.str_input.pop(0)
    if len(Global.str_input) != 0:
        create_words()
    ##### CREATE THE FINAL PREVIOUS WORD #####
    else:
        ya_done()

create_words()
```

Now this is just an example, I wrote it very quickly but I still face the exact same issue. Now if I remove the second list in the Dog list i.e. [1, 3]

Example:

```
class Dog():
    wolf = ['fat', 'small']
```

It runs fine and returns the value "1" as it should for the word "small."

How can I find the position of an item in a list within a list?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: It's a bit unclear from your question what it is that you're trying to solve. Are you just looking to find either the word 'fat' or 'small' in a sentence that gets passed in?

Comment: No. I'm trying to find the position of the word 'small' in the list. I can do it if the dog list contains only one list(for instance:[fat, small]). If the list contains more than one list it cannot find the position of 'small' in the list within a list(for instance ([[fat, small],[1, 3]]). Under "def ya_done()", the exec line is the main thing I'm trying to correct so I can make it work.  my question is exactly: How can I find the position of an item in a list within a list? Do I use .index and define the list I'm trying to search, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 solutions that you can use.

The first solution will collect every row positions with your word and the word position into them.

```
wolf = [['fat', 'small'],[1, 3]]

def get_positions(lists, word):
    i = 0
    for list in lists:
        if word in list:
            index = list.index(word)
            print "List Position: " + str(i) + "\nWord Postion: " + str(index) + "\n"
        i += 1

get_positions(wolf, "small")
```

Ouput:

```
List Position: 0
Word Postion: 1
```

Here is an example with multiple rows with that word.

```
example2 = [['fat', 'small'],[1, 'fat']]

get_positions(example2, "fat")
```

Output

```
List Position: 0
Word Postion: 0

List Position: 1
Word Postion: 1
```

The second solution, you have to provide the array, nested array position and the word, and it will return you the index position of this nested array:

```
wolf = [['fat', 'small'],[1, 3]]

def get_positions(lists, list_index, word):
    result = False
    if word in lists[list_index]:
        result = lists[list_index].index(word)
    return result

print get_positions(wolf, 0, "small")
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Thanks man! I'm going to use this if you don't mind! It is a much cleaner way of finding the position of an item in a given list, I changed it slightly because I have to constantly put in new variables with formatting to return different results.

Comment: How do i store the output('1') to a global variable and then use it to pull up the same word? How would you write that? because i tried to store it to a global variable in then use something like `class Global(): coat = "" int_store = 0; exec(f"""if Global.prv_word in Dog.{Global.cur_word}[0]:
                Global.int_store = Dog.{Global.cur_word}[0].index('{Global.prv_word}')
                Global.coat = Dog.{Global.cur_word}[1][{Global.int_store}]`but when I try to store the value '1' it doesn't actually seem to store it. Do you know of anyway to make a global variable store the output?

Comment: @Zoetyc : So now you have two solutions that provide different output. Took the one that fit the most with your need. :)

Comment: Thanks! I actually didn't know how to mark the question answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> biglist = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> print biglist[0]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print biglist[1]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print biglist[0].index('b')
1
```

Comment: It doesn't work for what I'm trying to do. I tried adding `[0]` to `exec(f"""if Global.prv_word in Dog.{Global.cur_word}:
    print(Dog.{Global.cur_word}[0].index('{Global.prv_word}'))""")` and it runs but also doesn't print the position, I thought something like this would work but it doesn't

Comment: `Dog` only has one attribute, named `wolf`.  If `Global.cur_word` isn't "wolf", I don't see how `Dog.{Global.cur_word}[0]` can possibly work.

Comment: You are right. With this limited example we know Global.cur_word will be wolf because wolf is the last word to run through pop but I didn't set up my arguments correctly! Thank you. Both you and Randy helped me see my error. The problem was I didn't specify the list, by adding [0] to the first if statement it was able to run through the rest of the arugment check it out: `exec(f"""if Global.prv_word in Dog.{Global.cur_word}[0]:
    print(Dog.{Global.cur_word}[0].index('{Global.prv_word}'))""")` it returned `1` like it should

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having here is that the actual elements of your list are lists themselves. If you look for the whole list, you'll find their positions:

```
In [13]: a = [[1, 2, 3], ['fat', 'small']]

In [14]: a.index(['fat', 'small'])
Out[14]: 1

In [15]: a.index([1, 2, 3])
Out[15]: 0
```

If what you actually want is to look through each sublist, you'll have to use `.index` on each of the sublists. You could do that with a for loop or a comprehension:

```
In [16]: [l.index('small') for l in a if 'small' in l]
Out[16]: [1]
```

This will come back with a list of all occurrences of your target word. If you know it only shows up once, you can then just grab that off the resulting list to get a number:

```
In [17]: [l.index('small') for l in a if 'small' in l][0]
Out[17]: 1
```

Comment: The problem was I didn't specify the list, by adding [0] to the first if statement it was able to run through the rest of the arugment check it out: `exec(f"""if Global.prv_word in Dog.{Global.cur_word}[0]: print(Dog.{Global.cur_word}[0].index('{Global.prv_word}'))""")` this helped me, such a silly error. Now could I make a variable equal the result of the output "1"? for instance instead of using print could I do `exec(f"""if Global.prv_word in Dog.{Global.cur_word}[0]:
    temp_var = Dog.{Global.cur_word}[0].index('{Global.prv_word}')""")`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question I asked(and made apparent very quickly) is I needed to specify the list that I'm trying to find the word in. By adding [0] to my list index query, I specified which list I wanted to index and I was able to pull the result I expected. In this case it is '1'(The word 'small', is in the second position of the 1st list, for those who don't know... lists always start with a 0 index, so 0 is the first position and '1' is the second position. In other words I searched the 1st list for a word and it returned '1' when it found the word in the second position). On to the next problem!

```
def ya_done():
        ##### WHY CAN'T I FIND THE POSITION? :( #####
        print(Global.prv_word)
        print(Global.cur_word)
        print(Global.nxt_word)
        ##### PRINT POSITION OF ADJECTIVE DESCRIBING DOG IN DOG LIST #####
        exec(f"""if Global.prv_word in Dog.{Global.cur_word}[0]:
        print(Dog.{Global.cur_word}.index('{Global.prv_word}'))""")
```